# Change Log4J Configuration for Apache Storm Topology

Tags: java, apache, log4j, apache-storm

I'm currently submitting Storm topologies programatically via my Java application by using the following command:

```
Nimbus.Client client = NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(stormConfigProvider.getStormConfig()).getClient();
client.submitTopology(
        this.topologyID.toString(),
        stormJarManager.getRemoteJarLocation(),
        JSONValue.toJSONString(stormConfigProvider.getStormConfig()),
        topology
);
```

In my scenario, I have two kinds of topologies. Testing topologies and production topologies. For both kind of topologies, I require different types of logging. While the testing topologies run with TRACE level, the production topologies will run with INFO level. In addition, I require that the production topologies have a SPLUNK Log4J2 appender configured, to centralize the logging of my production application.

For that, I included a log4j.xml file into my topology JAR which configures the SPLUNK appender. However, the log4j.xml file is not honored by the Server. Instead, the Storm Server seems to use its own configuration.

How can I change my log4j configuration for different topologies? (I don't want to modify the log4j.xml on each worker).

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://storm.apache.org/releases/current/dynamic-log-level-settings.html to set log levels for each topology.

I'm not sure how you'd add/remove the splunk appender based on the loaded topology. You might be able to configure log4j programatically https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html and set the `log4j2.configurationFactory` system property on your workers to point to your configuration factory (you can do this by adding it to the `topology.worker.childopts` property in your topology config).

Just for context, here's where Storm sets the system property that causes Log4j to load the worker log4j configuration https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/4137328b75c06771f84414c3c2113e2d1c757c08/storm-server/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/daemon/supervisor/BasicContainer.java#L560. If you wanted to load a log4j2.xml included in your topology jar, maybe it would be possible to conditionally exclude that setting from the system properties set for workers. I think it would require a code change though, so you'd need to raise an issue on https://issues.apache.org/jira