# Configuring logback with Storm

Tags: maven, logback, apache-storm, maven-shade-plugin

I have a storm project for which I have added some custom logback configurations using `logback.xml` (added configs to write logs to an index). When I build the jar and deploy the same on the cluster, I get the multiple bindings errors for this class `StaticLoggerBinder.class` due to it being present both in my jar and storm's own dependency list. Below is the error

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/storm/apache-storm-1.2.2/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/app/test/test-storm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

This causes none of my custom configs to be picked up. 
When I remove the conflicting jar from Storm's `lib` folder, my `logback.xml` configs are reflected and my logs are written to the index with no issues. I also see these logs in the beginning when I deploy the topology showing the configs I have added

```
22:05:13,818 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/app/test/test-storm-0.0.55-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/logback.xml]
22:05:13,839 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@19bb089b - URL [jar:file:/app/test/test-storm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
22:05:14,094 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
22:05:14,097 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [CONSOLE]
22:05:14,102 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
22:05:14,125 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender]
22:05:14,126 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [SPLUNK]
22:05:14,132 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.test] to INFO
22:05:14,132 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [com.test] to false
22:05:14,132 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [SPLUNK] to Logger[com.test]
22:05:14,133 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[com.test]
22:05:14,133 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
22:05:14,133 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[ROOT]
22:05:14,133 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
```

However, I do not want to take this route since it cannot be maintained so I decided use the `maven-shade-plugin` to relocate the `org.slf4j.impl` to `org.shaded.slf4j.impl`. Now when I deploy the topology there is no multiple bindings anymore, however my `logback.xml` is not honored and none of my configs are reflected nor do I see the above messages. It probably falls back to using a different logger.

How can I make my configs to be reflected when I deploy the topology? Please help. (Storm Version 1.2.2)

Comment: Could you share us your pom.xml? or a demo of your maven project. I think is a mistake in your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Storm switched from Logback to Log4j2 a few years ago. You can configure Log4j2 via the storm/log4j2/worker.xml and storm/log4j2/cluster.xml files. The former configures logging for your topology, as well as the worker JVM.

You should exclude logback from your fat jar.

Please also see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229035/8845188.